# Error Salesforce data query - [{'message': 'INVALID_HEADER_TYPE', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_AUTH_HEADER'}]

Tags: rest-api, python, simple-salesforce

I am trying the get data from Salesforce using simple_salesforce python package.
But I am getting Response content: [{'message': 'INVALID_HEADER_TYPE', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_AUTH_HEADER'}] when I execute any query or salesforce.Account.describe()

Below is the code, I wrote. Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong. I passed my access token as session id, how can I pass it as authorization:bearer {token}? If that is the issue.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import redis
import configparser
import pandas as pd
import json

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
configSFUrl = config.get("sf.server.com","SF_BASE_URLS")


def sf_get_acctoken():
    r_client = redis.Redis(
        host='xxxxxxxxx',  //my redis host name
        port=6379, 
        password='yyyyyyyy' // my redis password
    )
    token_Val = r_client.get('zzzzzzzzzz')
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    print("Access Token value from redis: {}" .format(token_Val))  // I get my access token printed here
    print("---------------------------------------------------")
    return token_Val

sf_token = sf_get_acctoken()
sf = Salesforce(instance=configSFUrl, session_id='.format(sf_token)')

desc = sf.Account.describe()  
print(desc)

sf_response = sf.query_all("SELECT ActivityDate, StartDateTime, Appointment_Status__c, Event_Type__c FROM Event WHERE StartDateTime = 'TODAY' AND Appointment_Status__c = 'Completed'")
print("JSON Output::" + json.loads(sf_response))

sf_df = pd.DataFrame(sf_response['records']).drop(columns='attributes')
print("Dataframe--------")
print(sf_df.head(5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
sf = Salesforce(instance=configSFUrl, session_id='.format(sf_token)')
```

You are sending the literal string `.format(sf_token)`. Just pass `sf_token` itself directly as the `session_id` parameter.

In Python 3, if you want to convert bytes into a string, you have to decode them:

```
some_bytes.decode('ascii')
```

where the parameter is the desired encoding, such as `ascii` or `utf-8`. Presumably an access token is ASCII.

Comment: The reason I am doing is my sf_token is in JWT (bytes). It need to be string format. If I changed it to as mentioned then I am getting this error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sdatta/Documents/Workspace/ProcessJson/salesforceIntegration.py", line 27, in <module>
    sf = Salesforce(instance=configSFUrl, session_id=sf_token)
  File "C:\Users\sdatta\Documents\Workspace\.venv\lib\site-packages\simple_salesforce\api.py", line 182, in __init__
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.session_id,
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Comment: @sudeep JWT isn't an access token. You have to exchange it for the access token or extract access token from it, depending on how you acquired the JWT. Example from David Reed: https://gist.github.com/davidmreed/5f4b7b8436487f9da9f682ca97f12cd9

Comment: @identigral I have my API token cached and I am accessing the latest token using redis which is actually storing the login token key. That key when passed to session_id, I am getting the concatenate error.

Comment: You said in your first comment that what you were getting was a JWT. A JWT and an access token are not the same thing. Which do you have?

Comment: More generally, in Python (3), you must *decode* bytes into a string before you perform string operations upon it. But that's a symptom, not the real problem. You need to get clarity on how you're supposed to be authenticating here.

Comment: My latest cache is storing the access token. Yes, with decode it worked.

Comment: Then you need to decode it. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your input @david